# Getting a "Chek internet connection" error while downloading.csv files from using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to download a **CSV** file from the url using the Chrome extension. For that, I have used `chrome.downloads.download`, but this gives me a check on my internet connection while I have a stable internet connection on my system.
How can I resolve this issue?

This is my code:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  chrome.downloads.download(
    {
      url: extensionFileURL,
      filename: `${downloadFolderPath}/${ReportName}`,
      saveAs: false,
      conflictAction: "uniquify",
    },
    function (downloadId) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error("Download Error:", chrome.runtime.lastError);
        reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
      } else {
        console.log("File downloaded with ID: ${downloadId}");
        console.log(
          "Downloaded file path: ${downloadFolderPath}/${ReportName}"
        );
        resolve("${downloadFolderPath}/${ReportName}");
      }
    }
  );
} else {
  const error = new Error("No internet connection");
  console.error("Internet Connection Error:", error);
  reject(error);
}
```